# Impossible to parse Vue file and import it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this Vue file, which is a component that shows the progress.

```
<script setup>
    const props = defineProps(['currentStep']);
    const steps = [1, 2, 3];
</script>


<nav aria-label="Progrès">
    <ol role="list" class="flex items-center">
        <li v-for="step in steps" class="relative pr-8 sm:pr-20">
            <div class="absolute inset-0 flex items-center" aria-hidden="true">
                <div :class="{
                    'h-0.5 w-full bg-orange-600': (currentStep >= step),
                    'h-0.5 w-full bg-gray-200': !(currentStep >= step)
                }"
                ></div>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="relative flex h-8 w-8 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-orange-600 hover:bg-orange-900">
                <svg v-if="(currentStep > step)" class="h-5 w-5 text-white" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.704 4.153a.75.75 0 01.143 1.052l-8 10.5a.75.75 0 01-1.127.075l-4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 011.06-1.06l3.894 3.893 7.48-9.817a.75.75 0 011.05-.143z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                </svg>
                <span v-if="(currentStep == step)" class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-orange-600" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span v-if="(currentStep < step)" class="h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-transparent group-hover:bg-gray-300" aria-hidden="true"></span>


                <span class="sr-only">Étape 1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

"currentStep" is a number between 1 and 4.

When I try to import this component in another component, I get the following error: "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.
"

How can I fix this error? Everything looks good to me.

Comment: What's the file name?

Comment: @Unmitigated RegisterProgress.vue. It is imported like this: "import RegisterProgress from "@/Components/RegisterProgress.vue";"

Comment: There's no <template> in the code you posted.